# Using double values instead of singular

Tags: php

In the code below how can I make it use `01` etc instead of `1`? and also how can I make it so that the previous link shows `01` as the limit page instead of `0`

**Code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page']) >=99){
 exit('ran out of pages');
//no idea what you want here :-)
}

if(empty($_GET['page']) OR !is_int($_GET['page'])){
$_GET['page']=01; 


$next=$_GET['page']+01;
$prev=$_GET['page']-1;
echo '<li><a href="branding-' .$next. '">Next</a></li>';
echo '<li><a href="branding-' .$prev. '">Prev</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: [`str_pad($_GET['page'], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)`](http://codepad.org/rJQyY5Ow) The question is, why?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks,  I did come across that wasn't sure of formatting - would I set that as a var?

Comment: I'm curious why you need to do this too. The variables only appear within HTML attributes so they're not even user visible

Answer (score 0):

[`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/function.sprintf.php) is perfect for this

```
// read current page, defaulting to 1
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? max((int) $_GET['page'], 1) : 1;

$next = $page + 1;
$prev = max($page - 1, 1); // don't go below 1
// ending the PHP context here. Echo-ing strings of HTML is cumbersome
?>
<li><a href="branding-<?= sprintf('%02d', $next) ?>">Next</a></li>
<li><a href="branding-<?= sprintf('%02d', $prev) ?>">Prev</a></li>
```

Also, don't assign numbers with a leading zero. PHP will attempt to read them as octal numbers.